# Load Google Map Using Custom Field In WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I want to show up google maps on different posts based on the custom field data which will be containing google-maps address such as http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Kathmandu,+Nepal&hl=en&z=13. What plugin should I use for this? Or what modification should I make to the theme in single.php? Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward using the Google Maps JS API documentation and the WordPress Codex. What have you tried and what part do you need help with?

Comment: I am sorry, because I am new to wordpress and stuffs, I did not had any idea working with custom fields. Is it wrong for a novice to ask here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Google Maps in your wordpress with these plugins:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-maps-for-wordpress/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/

http://avi.alkalay.net/2006/11/google-maps-plugin-for-wordpress.html